# databinding 3 axis chart in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I want to form 3 axis chart x,y,y1 in c# and i want to know how to bind the 3rd y1 axis in WPF

I add data into collection like this

```
dbCollectionfuelvsunit.Add(
    new VM.Chart.AxisDatatablekwhvsfuel(
        Convert.ToInt32(DG1),
        Convert.ToInt32(Time),
        Convert.ToInt32(fuel)));
```

Bind it like this

```
((ColumnSeries)this.chart.chart.Series[0]).ItemsSource = dbCollectionfuelvsunit;
```

In my xmal i bind the x and y axis which works like like

```
<Grid>
        <dvc:Chart Name="chart">
            <dvc:Chart.Series>
                <dvc:ColumnSeries Title="DG 1"
                  IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Time}"
                  DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=DG1}" />
```

Jow do I bind the fuel collection in my XML?

Comment: From memory there's two ways, 1) You can add any number of axis at the Chart layer 2) You can add another series to the chart that shows the fuel as they will all appear on same graph.

Comment: @JohnPeters thanks, could you show me with an example ?